# Unable to understand this Deferred code

Tags: jquery

I came across this piece of code in this thread [jQuery: load scripts in order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9711160/jquery-load-scripts-in-order/9711278#9711278)

```
    var deferred = new $.Deferred(),
        pipe = deferred;

    $.each(scripts , function(i, val) {
         pipe = pipe.pipe(function() {
             return  $.getScript(val, function() {
                 console.log('loaded '+ val);
             });
         });
    });

deferred.resolve();
```

Line by line, What does this code do?

Comment: You may want to know that as of jQuery 1.8, `.pipe()` is deprecated and should be replaced by `.then()`.

Comment: Ok thanks. Can you please explain what is the code doing? I know it's calling a bunch of scripts one after other loads, but if I go ahead and read the code line by line, i have no idea what's going on

Comment: I would make an answer if I understood it myself, but I don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original problem was to load a set of JS scripts sequentially, i.e. one by one. A nice property of `.then` (previously `.pipe`) is that the new promise returned by `.then` is resolved when the promise returned by the callback is resolved.

A small example:

```
var promiseA = promise.then(function() {
    return promiseB; // assume this is defined somewhere
});
```

Here, `promiseA` is resolved once `promiseB` is resolved. We can use this property to execute asynchronous functions sequentially. If you want to load three scripts, A, B and C, one after each other, you can do:

```
load(A).then(function() {
    // executed when promise returned by load(A) is resolved
    return load(B);
}).then(function() {
    // executed when promise returned by load(B) is resolved
    return load(C);
});
```

And that's what the above code is doing, just for a variable number of scripts:

```
// create a new deferred object
var deferred = new $.Deferred(),
// assign it to a new variables to keep a reference to the original deferred object
// so that we can resolve it later
    pipe = deferred; 

// iterate over an array of URLs
$.each(scripts , function(i, val) {
     // for each URL do this
     // overwrite the `pipe` variable with the new promise so that
     // the next iteration can use the new promise
     pipe = pipe.pipe(function() {
         // this is executed when the (i-1)th script loaded
         // load the ith script
         return  $.getScript(val);
     });
});

// resolve the original (first) promise
deferred.resolve();
```

Maybe the loop is what is confusing you. If you had a fixed number of scripts, it would be equivalent to:

```
var deferred = new $.Deferred();
var pipe = deferred;


pipe = pipe.then(function() {
    return $.getScript(scripts[0]));
});

pipe = pipe.then(function() {
    return $.getScript(scripts[1]));
});

pipe = pipe.then(function() {
    return $.getScript(scripts[2]));
});


deferred.resolve();
```